# Override an attribute with a property in python class

Tags: python, inheritance, properties

I have a class like:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, a1 = None, a2 = None):
        someInitialization()
        self.a1 = a1
        self.a2 = a2

    def coolMethod(self): 
        return dosomething(self.a2)
```

Let's say that

- I don't want to modify the attributes of the parent class
- I don't want to provide a1 and a2 at initialization because they are expensive to compute (and they are not needed by every method of Parent)
- I don't want to remember which of the methods of Parent requires a1 or a2, they should just work

**EDIT** my actual constraints are not really so strict, but I ask this question also for understanding better the class attributes, methods, etc..

I am using the simplest solution without initialization inheritance:

```
class Child(Parent):
    _propertiesCache = {'a1':None,'a2':None}
    def _initProperty(self, propertyName):
        value = self._propertiesCache[propertyName]
        if value is None:
            self._propertiesCache[propertyName]=expensiveFunction(self.b, propertyName)
        return  self._propertiesCache[propertyName]

    @property
    def a1(self):
        return self._initProperty('a1')

    @property
    def a2(self):
        return self._initProperty('a2')

    def __init__(self,b):
        self.b = b
        someInitialization()
```

Is there a way to properly call the initialization of the parent class? If I use `super(Child,self).__init__()` I get `AttributeError: can't set attribute`.
I tried to override `__new__` but I am always missing something

```
class Child(Parent):
    _propertiesCache = {'a1':None,'a2':None}
    @classmethod
    def _initProperty(cls, propertyName):
        value = cls._propertiesCache[propertyName]
        if value is None:
            cls._propertiesCache[propertyName] = someTimeConsumingFunctionThatIDontWantToCallAtInitialization(propertyName)
        return  cls._propertiesCache[propertyName]

    @property
    def a1(self):
        return self._initProperty('a1')

    @property
    def a2(self):
        return self._initProperty('a2')

    def __new__(cls):
        super(Child,cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls
    def __init__(self,b):
        self.b = b
        super(Child,self).__init__(a1=self.a1, a2=self.a2)
```

Gives me:

```
>>c = Child();c.a1
<property at 0x3aa4228>
>>c.a1.fget(c)
"ValueOfa1"
```

Comment: Have you considered making the `Parent` an abstract base class, and `a1` a required property? See https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html

Comment: Can you make `a` getter method, which computes `self.a` if it doesn't exist, and then returns `self.a`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the suggestion, it's an overkill for my actual use case but it's something I should look at, in general!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of calling your method `_initProperty` call it `__getattr__` so that it will be called every time the attribute is not found in the normal places it should be stored (the attribute dictionary, class dictionary etc.) then the first time the attribute is tried to be accessed it gets initialized.

Be sure to not set them in the Parent initialization, maybe only set them if they are not None:

```
class Parent:
     def __init__(self,a1=None,a2=None):
         if a1 is not None:
             self.a1 = a1
         if a2 is not None:
             self.a2 = a2
```

As well to stay consistent with errors you will want to raise an `AttributeError` if the attribute doesn't exist instead of letting the `KeyError` go through, and maybe add a reference to the value in the regular attribute dict so that it doesn't need to run the `__getattr__` every time:

```
_propertiesCache = {'a1':None,'a2':None}
def __getattr__(self, propertyName):
    if propertyName not in self._propertiesCache:
        raise AttributeError(propertyName)
    value = self._propertiesCache[propertyName]
    if value is None:
        value = self._propertiesCache[propertyName]=expensiveFunction(self.b, propertyName)
    setattr(self,propertyName,value)
    return  value
```

Any way you implement this you need to make sure:

The attribute is not set until the first time they are used (at which point `__getattr__` gets used)

Comment: That's the best solution but OP would need to change parent class to remove self.a and self.b initialization from parent class. You should probably mention that. Otherwise `__getattr__` will never be called for `self.a` and `self.b`

Comment: @MuhammadTahir in the first example of Child the super `__init__` is never called but I didn't notice it's use in the second implementation.  You raise a good point that it should be mentioned regardless.

Comment: Also your __getattr__ definition can be like `if attr == 'b': self.b = calculate_b(); return self.b; else: raise AttributeError` No need to use property cache. As once you do `self.b = calculate_b()` `__getattr__` will never be called again for `self.b`. It will be available by python's other methods.

Comment: @MuhammadTahir, I was under the impression that only the attributes for `a1` and `a2` needed to be calculated as needed, and that their value should be stored in the class definition as that is how it is defined in both of the OP's test cases.  `self.b` is set in the Child initialization so I don't think it is an issue.

Comment: @MuhammadTahir actually self.b it's only set in the child initialization. Luckily my requirements are more relaxed than what I wrote in the original question, so I am modifying the parent class initialization

Answer (score 1):

I believe that much more pythonic and in line with the OOP convention is not to change the `Parent` class - it does not have to anticipate how its children  override its arguments and behavior.

In order for `Child` to use `a1` and `a2` as properties it has to implement both the getter (`@property`) and dummy setter (`@a1.setter`).

The code below assumes that `a1` could not be modified by user (so the setter is implemented as a dummy and `__init__` of Parent is called with arbitrary value). Property `a2` has slightly more complicated behavior: it could be initialized or modified by user, but if its value is not valid (e.g. negative here) - it is overridden by internal logic.

```py
class Child(Parent):    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None, -42)


    @property
    def a1(self):
        return 42

    @a1.setter
    def a1(self, value):
        """ Do nothing. Implemented to prevent Attribute Error """


    @property
    def a2(self):
        if getattr(self, '_a2', -1) < 0:
            self._a2 = self._initProperty('a2')
        return self._a2

    @a2.setter
    def a2(self, value):
        self._a2 = value
```

P.S. You could reduce the dummy setter to just one line:

```py
class Child(Parent):    
    # ...
    a1 = a1.setter(lambda self, value: None)
```